# Why does PyQt5 QPixmap crash python?

Tags: python, crash, pyqt5, qpixmap

When I try and convert this list of strings to a pixmap it crashes python. 
Any suggestions to pix this?

```
openIcon = [
    '16 13 5 1',
    '. c #040404',
    '# c #808304',
    'a c None',
    'b c #f3f704',
    'c c #f3f7f3',
    'aaaaaaaaa...aaaa',
    'aaaaaaaa.aaa.a.a',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaa..a',
    'a...aaaaaaaa...a',
    '.bcb.......aaaaa',
    '.cbcbcbcbc.aaaaa',
    '.bcbcbcbcb.aaaaa',
    '.cbcb...........',
    '.bcb.#########.a',
    '.cb.#########.aa',
    '.b.#########.aaa',
    '..#########.aaaa',
    '...........aaaaa'
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
    openIcon_p = QPixmap(openIcon)
    openIcon_p.save("openIcon.png")
```

Using:

Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

PyQt5==5.13.0

Comment: change to `from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QPixmap
    app = QGuiApplication([])
    openIcon_p = QPixmap(openIcon)
    openIcon_p.save("openIcon.png")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run the code from console to see the error messages.
You need a `QApplication` before `QPixmap`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys

openIcon = [
    '16 13 5 1',
    '. c #040404',
    '# c #808304',
    'a c None',
    'b c #f3f704',
    'c c #f3f7f3',
    'aaaaaaaaa...aaaa',
    'aaaaaaaa.aaa.a.a',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaa..a',
    'a...aaaaaaaa...a',
    '.bcb.......aaaaa',
    '.cbcbcbcbc.aaaaa',
    '.bcbcbcbcb.aaaaa',
    '.cbcb...........',
    '.bcb.#########.a',
    '.cb.#########.aa',
    '.b.#########.aaa',
    '..#########.aaaa',
    '...........aaaaa'
    ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
    openIcon_p = QtGui.QPixmap(openIcon)
    openIcon_p.save("openIcon.png")
```

Edit: without the added line the code gives the following error message:

```
QPixmap::fromImageInPlace: QPixmap cannot be created without a QGuiApplication
QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap
```

for explanation see [Qt-Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#details). there is also a description when to use `QtWidgets.QApplication` and when `QtGui.QGuiApplication` as commented by eyllanesc

Comment: No need for QApplication, just QGuiApplication, remove `sys.exit(app.exec_())` is unnecessary

Comment: Strange - why would I need a QGuiApplication? Why would that crash Python?

Comment: see the edit of my answer

Comment: @eyllanesc: i follwed the error message, but didn't recognize QGuiApplication :-)

Comment: @a_manthey_67 QGuiApplicaton belong QtGui